# sshpass doesn't work with some servers?

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

Using `sshpass` in bash script. 
I am connecting to the server, send the command `df -h` and save the output in a txt file.

It works fine with about 10 servers. I found it doesn't work with some other servers and I don't understand why. Servers are same. So same OS, same hardware etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 60 /usr/bin/sshpass -p 'mypassword.' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@11.22.33.44 /usr/sbin/vtysh > /var/www/output/11-22-33-44.txt << EOF
df -h
EOF

sleep 5;

timeout 60 /usr/bin/sshpass -p 'mypassword.' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@55.66.77.88 /usr/sbin/vtysh > /var/www/output/55-66-77-88.txt << EOF
df -h
EOF

etc.
```

In some servers I see only:

```
/bin/login: invalid option -- q
Tinylogin v1.4 (2018.03.23-08:44+0000) multi-call binary

Usage: login [OPTION]... [username] [ENV=VAR ...]

Options:
    -f      Do not perform authentication (user already authenticated
    -h      Name of the remote host for this login.
    -p      Preserve environment.
```

Bash script is absolutely same, no changes there (only IP address).
Will be very thankful for help.

Comment: Often ssh will issue a login command to get a command prompt. On next the syntax seems to be slightly different. `sshpass` is essentially a wrapper around the ssh client that will "type" the password as if you typed it yourself. It works very similarly to an `expect` script. As login issued an error it were unable to log into the system.
Have you tried the -v option to see if there is additional output that could help?

Comment: Even if it is the same OS, the version of the sshd or its config can vary.

Comment: what's the result of `grep -i 'MaxSession' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`? it that 10?